# Interface as property in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In some Fragments and other classes (in Java) I have a `public interface ISomeActions` with functions that I then call from some other parts in that class, to denote actions. So, I have a `ISomeListener listener` that I set in the constructor, or right after I create an object of `SomeClass`. How can I achieve this in Kotlin?

Example:

```java
public class SomeClass{
    public ISomeListener listener;
    public interface ISomeListener{
       public void doSomething();
    }

    void actuallyDoSomething(){
        listener.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I think I can use a `lateinit var listener : SomeListener`, but I don't know if that would be adequate. The member is an Interface, and not an implementation of that Interface in case it's called after the Activity finishes.

Comment: you want interface demo in kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Constructor

```
class MyClass(private val myInterface: MyInterface) { ... }
```

This way `myInterface` is immutable. You can be sure that this will never be null.

2) After object creation - `null`

```
class MyClass(var myInterface: MyInterface? = null) { ... }
```

Now `myInterface` is mutable and can be null at any time. You can safety access it via `myInterface?.someMethod()` (is `myInterface` is null call won't be invoked). To access and assign listener use `myClassInstance.myInterface = myInterfaceInstance`.

Because of default param you can create your class with or without constructor param:

```
val myClass1 = MyClass()
val myClass2 = MyClass(interfaceInstanceOrNull)
```

3) After object creation - `lateinit`

```
class MyClass(myInterface: MyInterface? = null) {
    lateinit var _myInterface: MyInterface
    init {
        if (myInterface != null) { _myInterface = myInterface }
    }
}
```

In my opinion the worst solution. `lateinit` is designed for injecting field after creation, for DI frameworks like dagger. If you try call method on `myInterface` if it is not init yet `UninitializedPropertyAccessException` will be thrown. You can check if property is initlialized like this:

```
if (::_myProperty.isInitialized) { _myProperty.doSth() }
```

In my opinion you should use the first or the second approach. As I understand you cannot always init object with instance of MyInterface, so the second one seems legit for your puroposes.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to clarify! I think I'll use the second approach.

Comment: If MyClass is a Fragment in Android, where non-default constructors are supposed to be avoided, is it better to pass it in the arguments, or as a nullable property of the fragment?

Comment: Actually you should use `newInstance` pattern (static method creating fragment and applying bundle to new fragment). See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/7508302